# avoid page counting when click refresh button

Tags: php

I made a php script to counts the number of  users have viewed  my website's pages. This is my code

```
<?php   
    require_once ('test.php');

    $institute_id = 14;

    $q = "INSERT INTO page_views2 ( institute_id, views) VALUES ( $institute_id, 1)
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views=views+1"
         ; 
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

?>
```

I added this to top of my webpages and this is working (views incrementing) properly when I open the pages. But my problem is When I refresh the page, page views is incrementing by 1. It is okey when it is open first time. But I want to avoid from this when someone is refreshing the page.

so can any body tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Is it really that important to not count refreshes?

Comment: @Jack: If the point is to count unique visits, or page reads, than it probably is.

Comment: I need to count page reads only.

Comment: If I go back to the overview and click the same page again, is that considered a refresh or should it count as a new page visit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sessions?

```
require_once ('test.php');

$institute_id = 14;

//if no such session exists, assume that its their first time viewing.
if(!isset($_SESSION[$institute_id.'_v'])){

    //insert
    $q = "INSERT INTO page_views2 ( institute_id, views) VALUES ( $institute_id, 1)
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views=views+1"
         ; 
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

    //set session variable saying they've viewed this institutions page.
    $_SESSION[$institute_id.'_v'] = 1;

}
```

Comment: -1. If there are 100 institute pages viewed, you'd end up with 100 cookies :(

Comment: Point taken. Changed to sessions.

Comment: Better. Don't forget the all important `session_start()` though :)

Comment: unset($_SESSION[$institute_id.'_v']);

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing a page results in a new page request, so it obviously triggers your script on the server side. There's no way to alter this behaviour. What you can do is to implement some kind of checking, if the user requested the same page again (refresh) or not. You can store some info in your session/cookies and then just compare the values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies or sessions for that, I guess. Make a session variable that holds a timestamp of the latest visit. If the same page gets loaded again within an hour or so, the counter does not increase.

Comment: can you explain it with an example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use 2 variables, one to define the name of each page you are visiting and one $_SESSION variable. You can set the $_SESSION with the name of the page you are viewing after you increment a counter with the query. Make the control variable each time before making the  increment query and if the session variable has the same name as the page you are viewing skip the increment operation. Hope that helps.

Comment: can you give me an example with your answer. thank you very much

Comment: In each page you can try with something like this : `$page = 'index';    if($_SESSION['last_page_visited'] != $page ) {                        (here put your counting query); 
    $_SESSION['last_page_visited'] = $page; 
}`